# How to use 4-space wide tab character in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I'm creating a Flutter app in android studio. Under Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Dart, I enabled "use tab character" and changed the tab size and indent to 4.

However, nothing seemed to have changed in the main.dart file, so I used Ctrl-Alt-Shift-L to reformat the code (even tried with "code cleanup" enabled), but it still uses two spaces to indent.

How do I make android studio use tab characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still change the tab indents by manually editing the configuration files of Android Studio.

### Step 1

Open the configuration folder for codestyles:

**macOS**

- `~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudioXXXX.X/codestyles`

**Windows**

- `%AppData%\Google\AndroidStudioXXXX.X\codestyles` or
- `%AppData%\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioXXXX.X\codestyles`

**Linux**
*currently unknown sorry*

### Step 2

Add a new section into the file your IDE is using. Mine is `codestyles/Default.xml`.

Like this:

```
<code_scheme name="Default" version="173">
  ...
  <codeStyleSettings language="Dart">
    <option name="BRACE_STYLE" value="2" />
    <option name="METHOD_BRACE_STYLE" value="2" />
    <option name="ELSE_ON_NEW_LINE" value="true" />
    <indentOptions>
      <option name="INDENT_SIZE" value="4" />
      <option name="TAB_SIZE" value="4" />
    </indentOptions>
  </codeStyleSettings>
  ...
</code_scheme>
```

Comment: As of Android Studio 4.1, the file is in a new location -- at least on Windows: %APPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\codestyles.

Comment: This is unfortunately no longer a valid answer for Android Studio 2022.2.1
Does anybody know how to change the indentation for this version of Android Studio?

Comment: @Fredrik_Borgstrom I updated the paths to match the new locations

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio 2020.3
%AppData%\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\codestyles

Default.xml

I found the codestyles at the above location on a Windows 10 box.  Find the Dart section of the file.  Add the tab options you want.

```
  <codeStyleSettings language="Dart">
    <option name="RIGHT_MARGIN" value="1000" />
    <indentOptions>
      <option name="USE_TAB_CHARACTER" value="true" />
      <option name="INDENT_SIZE" value="4" />
      <option name="TAB_SIZE" value="4" />
    </indentOptions>
  </codeStyleSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Remark for Android Studio 4:** In Android Studio 3.6 and below, dartfmt could simply be disabled, as described by Astavie. Unfortunately, this function has been removed in Android Studio 4.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to disable Dartfmt under Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Dart

Comment: How did you do that? This option is not available for me. Using AS 4.1 on Linux.

Comment: just as @progNewbie I'm also dying to know how have you done it: currently the only option available is line length...

Answer (score 0):

If you are an Android Developer and cannot leave Android Studio, since it's your coding home, but can't let go of flutter either.

**Use a different theme: Visual Studio 2019 Dark Theme** (this auto adjusts indentation and makes code look exactly as of Visual Studio Code). To install theme - plugins -> search "Visual Studio 2019 Dark Theme"

**OR**

**Use a different font:** I prefer

Font : "Droid Sans Mono Slashed" or "Monospaced" (You can use any that works for spacing)

Font size: 18 , Line Height 1.4 // For 14 inch screens

Font size: 14 , Line Height 1.2 // For 15.6 inch screens or larger

[image]

OR

**A combination of above looks beautiful.**

[image]