# Configure tab size for Dart/Flutter in Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, indentation

I was using tab(size 6) for indention for flutter code in android studio.
After updating Android Studio to Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 code indention resets to 2 space tab.
I cant find option to change it.

**Is it possible to use tab indention of size 6 ?**

I am also considering using VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

Know it's been a bit on this, but you can change the tab -- just know they REALLY REALLY don't want you to do it.

You don't mention the OS and I'm currently on Windows.  On Windows, you edit the file located at `%APPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\codestyles\Default.xml` and add the following snippet just before the closing `</closeScheme>` tag:

```
  <codeStyleSettings language="Dart">
    <indentOptions>
      <option name="INDENT_SIZE" value="6" />
      <option name="TAB_SIZE" value="6" />
    </indentOptions>
  </codeStyleSettings>
```

File location will vary for other operating systems.  An answer to this question for an older version contains older locations on other operating systems: [How to use 4-space wide tab character in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578404/how-to-use-4-space-wide-tab-character-in-android-studio).

Those locations were identified in the above post as:

- macOS: ~/Library/Preferences/ CONFIGURATION_FOLDER.
- Linux: ~/.
  CONFIGURATION_FOLDER.

Configuration folder is the `AndroidStudio[xyz]/codestyles` folder -- AndroidStudio2020.3

Comment: i am using linux and i edited file as you instructed, its didn't worked. i switched to vscode anyways. I'll only use android studio when its absolutely necessary. though it annoys me to switch setups/env. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an Android Developer and cannot leave Android Studio, since it's your coding home, but can't let go of flutter either.

**Changing tab size won't work through `Default.xml` in `codestyles`.**

**Use a different theme: Visual Studio 2019 Dark Theme** (this auto adjusts indentation and makes code look exactly as of Visual Studio Code). To install theme - plugins -> search "Visual Studio 2019 Dark Theme"

**OR**

**Use a different font:** I prefer

Font : "Droid Sans Mono Slashed" or "Monospaced" (You can use any that works for spacing)

Font size: 18 , Line Height 1.4 // For 14 inch screens

Font size: 14 , Line Height 1.2 // For 15.6 inch screens or larger

[image]

**OR**

**A combination of above looks beautiful.**

[image]